# Table printing nil on Lua

Tags: lua, null, lua-table

I have this code written in Lua, it's just an example code, because the actual one I'm using is bigger than this, but this is the part I'm having problems.

Does anyone know why when I try to print what's inside the table `t` I get `nil` as result?

```
t = {
{name="John",sex="M",age=19},
{name="Susan",sex="F",age=20}
} 

for _ in ipairs(t) do 

    print("NAME: " .. t.name) 
    print("SEX: " .. t.sex) 
    print("AGE: " .. t.age)
    print("\n") 

end
```

I mean, this is the result I get when I run the code:

```
attempt to concatenate field 'name' (a nil value)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterating over `t` doesn't change `t`. You need to specify where to put the values you are iterating over, and use those variables.

```
local t = {
    {name="John",sex="M",age=19},
    {name="Susan",sex="F",age=20}
} 

for index, value in ipairs(t) do 
    print("NAME: " .. value.name) 
    print("SEX: " .. value.sex) 
    print("AGE: " .. value.age)
    print("\n") 
end
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that. Actually, this was a dumb example so I can change the original code I'm using on my project, I got data from a large text file and put them on a table, but I couldn't print those data, I tried now on the original code and it worked, so thank you!

Comment: @cfrancklin: You should also mark this answer as solving your problem by clicking on the green checkbox.